# org.apache.pdfbox.examples.signature.CreateVisableSignature is throwing null exception

Tags: java, digital-signature, pdfbox

I am having an issue with the sign() method in the CreateVisableSignature example throwing a null pointer exception on

```
    List<Certificate> certList = Arrays.asList(cert);
```

I think I need to create a certificate.  Can someone tell me how to do that?

Here is the offending code:

```
    public byte[] sign(InputStream content) throws SignatureException,
        IOException {
    CMSProcessableInputStream input = new CMSProcessableInputStream(content);
    CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
    // CertificateChain
    List<Certificate> certList = Arrays.asList(cert);
    CertStore certStore = null;
    try {
        certStore = CertStore.getInstance("Collection",
                new CollectionCertStoreParameters(certList), provider);
        gen.addSigner(privKey, (X509Certificate) certList.get(0),
                CMSSignedGenerator.DIGEST_SHA256);
        gen.addCertificatesAndCRLs(certStore);
        CMSSignedData signedData = gen.generate(input, false, provider);
        return signedData.getEncoded();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // should be handled
        System.err.println("Error while creating pkcs7 signature.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Problem while preparing signature");
}
```

This is the code that set it:

```
    /**
 * Initialize the signature creator with a keystore (pkcs12) and pin that
 * should be used for the signature.
 * 
 * @param keystore
 *            is a pkcs12 keystore.
 * @param pin
 *            is the pin for the keystore / private key
 */
public CreateVisibleSignature(KeyStore keystore, char[] pin) {
    try {
        /*
         * grabs the first alias from the keystore and get the private key.
         * An alternative method or constructor could be used for setting a
         * specific alias that should be used.
         */
        Enumeration<String> aliases = keystore.aliases();
        String alias = null;
        if (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
            alias = aliases.nextElement();
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not find alias");
        }
        privKey = (PrivateKey) keystore.getKey(alias, pin);
        cert = keystore.getCertificateChain(alias);
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not extract private key.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        System.err.println("Unknown algorithm.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is how I created the keystore:

```
keytool -genkeypair -storepass password1 -storetype pkcs12 -alias hhscms -validity 365 -keyalg RSA -keystore keystore.p12
```

Why is it that the following code can't get the cert?

```
        privKey = (PrivateKey) keystore.getKey(alias, pin);
        cert = keystore.getCertificateChain(alias);
```

This is the exception I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Arrays.asList(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.pdfbox.examples.signature.CreateVisibleSignature.sign(CreateVisibleSignature.java:191)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.doWriteSignature(COSWriter.java:767)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.visitFromDocument(COSWriter.java:1162)
at org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument.accept(COSDocument.java:578)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfwriter.COSWriter.write(COSWriter.java:1517)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.saveIncremental(PDDocument.java:1398)
at org.apache.pdfbox.examples.signature.CreateVisibleSignature.signPDF(CreateVisibleSignature.java:164)
at org.apache.pdfbox.examples.signature.CreateVisibleSignature.main(CreateVisibleSignature.java:238)
```

This is my pom.xml entries:

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
      <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15</artifactId>
      <version>1.44</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
      <artifactId>bcmail-jdk15</artifactId>
      <version>1.44</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-ext-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.52</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.52</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: the last argument should be -keystore keystore.p12.

Comment: I know that. I just recommend you to edit your question to that it looks nicer :-)

Comment: I am getting an alias of "CN=HHS CMS,OU=HHS,O=CMS,L=Baltimore,ST=MD,C=US" and a pin of "password1".  I think this correct.

Comment: I am getting an alias of "hhscms".

Comment: My code: 
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", new BouncyCastleProvider());
        char[] pin = "password1".toCharArray();
        keystore.load(new FileInputStream("keystore.p12"), pin);
        Enumeration<String> aliases = keystore.aliases();
        String alias = aliases.nextElement();
        System.out.println("alias: " + alias);
        PrivateKey privKey = (PrivateKey) keystore.getKey(alias, pin);
        Certificate[] cert = keystore.getCertificateChain(alias);
        System.out.println(cert.length);

Comment: This is strange.  This is what I got using your code:  alias: CN=hhs cms,OU=hhs,O=cms,L=Baltimore,ST=MD,C=US
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.pdfbox.examples.signature.CreateVisibleSignature.test(CreateVisibleSignature.java:119)
 at org.apache.pdfbox.examples.signature.CreateVisibleSignature.main(CreateVisibleSignature.java:231)  Are you running on windows and did you create the keystore.p12 file on the DOS command line?

Comment: I used the keytool.exe in c:\Program Files\Java\jdk*\bin .

Comment: That was it Tilman.  I was using the default which is pointing to the jre rather than the jdk version.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

As was pointed out by Tilman, you have to make sure that you are running the correct keytool.  In my case, keytool was pointing to the jre1.8 rather than the jdk1.8